# Program crashes due to NullReferenceException, and noone knows where

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

Im coding under VS 2010 and .net 4.0.3... SP1. In C# and WPF

My project is now pretty huge and include dll developed by other workmates, so I dont have access to the whole code of the thing.

The point is that almost randomly my program crashes (during debug) claiming unhandled NullReferenceException. There are several threads moving at the same time so it is a hell to know where it happened..

I googled and searched here and I found that people says that if you go

```
Debug>Exceptions>Common Language RunTime Exceptions> System.NullReferenceException
```

And set it to Thrown instead of User handle. It should stop where null reference occurs but it does not ..

In running time I can see how some thread freze (the output stop being reflected in the UI but other threads keep on (they do perform changes on the UI) and then, afetr some seconds, the whole thing crashes due to un handled NRE.

There is no callStack nor code to debug nor nothing, so I'm kind of stuck in here :S

This is all the help I get:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any suggestion ???

Comment: "There is no callStack", do you mean when you inspect the exception in your debugger, the `StackTrace` property is empty?

Comment: So, does this NRE get displayed in a popup with a line to code or not? Have you tried going to all your `DirectCast` events (If you have any) and changing it to `Try...Catch...End Try` and using a `MsgBox` to display `ex.message`?

Comment: Im sorry I dont know whats a DirectCast. Anyhow .. 
 is no callStack m

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio's [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx) option to better debug and find exceptions...
[Enable IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264944.aspx) and after the program crashes in Debug, you can use the IntelliTrace stack to find the origin of the exception.

From MSDN

> IntelliTrace records the exception type and message for these kinds of exceptions:
>    1.  Handled exceptions where the exception is thrown and caught
>    2.   Unhandled exceptions

Comment: Do I need VS Ultimate? Mine is VS 2010 v10.0.4
If search a bit around and found nothing ...

Comment: What do you mean by "Searched around"? From what I remember, it's available in VS 2010 Ultimate

Comment: searching around mean through the menus and googleing a bit .. I think that I have VS2010 profesional. And that is not the same that Ultimate so .. there is no IntellyTrace :(

Do you know if it is possible to reproduce the error using the pdb file ?

Comment: If you have the PDBs you and you enabled all the "Thrown" exceptions in the `Debug -> Exceptions` you should have caught the exception even if it came from another DLL...